# Functions with tablename as argument in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

How to create a function in postgresql with tablename as argument and the function returns the result set of table which is passed as argument for the query "select * from TABLE". Here the TABLE is the argument passed to the function.

Comment: See the examples in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Can you explain what you really want to do? A function of the type that you describe would be useless and complicated to use.

Comment: @Patrick  function named selectall(tablename). And the function execute "select * from tablename" and then the result set is returned.

Comment: But why do `SELECT * FROM selectall(tablename) AS t(columns...)` instead of simply `SELECT * FROM tablename`? Unless you have some other processing going on in the function it is useless. Tell us what that processing is and you'll get a good answer.

Comment: @Patrick  If I create a function as selectall(), then there is no need to specify each time as "select * from" for each table. So, If I create a table like this then it is easy like just pass the table name as argument and it returns the resultset of table just by calling "select selectall(student);"

Answer (score 5):

What you want is possible but completely and utterly useless.

The function you were asking for is this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION selectall(tbl name) RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I', tbl);
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You need a set returning function (SRF) because a table may have multiple rows. It needs to return `record` because different tables return different sets of columns. You **can not** use this SRF in a select list:

```
test=# SELECT selectall('student');
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function selectall(name) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

You can use it as a row source, but then the query becomes longer than a simple `SELECT * FROM student`. You **can not** use it just like so:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM selectall('student');
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM selectall('student');
```

You **can only use it** by specifying an alias and column definitions:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM selectall('student') AS t(id int, first_name text, col3 boolean, ...);
```

Now compare that to:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM student;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but no need for rudeness. This answer applies to more complicated situations too and is helpful for mine and the simplicity of his initial query helped me find this answer.